# Make form appear on click event

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="submit.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="phoneNumber" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Phone:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="major" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Major:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="major" name="major">
    </div>
  </div>

  <hr>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="itemForSale" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Item for Sale:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="itemForSale1" name="itemForSale1">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="quantity" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Quantity:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="quantity1" name="quantity1">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="price1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Price:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price1" name="price1">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="itemOneImg1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Image 1:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="file" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png" class="form-control" name="itemOneImg1">

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="itemOneImg2" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Image 2:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="file" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png" class="form-control" name="itemOneImg2">

    </div>
  </div>

  <hr>

  <!-- Two -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="itemForSale2" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Item for Sale:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="itemForSale2" name="itemForSale2">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="quantity2" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Quantity:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="quantity2" name="quantity2">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="major2" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Price:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price2" name="price2">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="itemTwoImg1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Image 1:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="file" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png" class="form-control" name="itemTwoImg1">

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="itemTwoImg2" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Image 2:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="file" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png" class="form-control" name="itemTwoImg2">

    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- END TWO -->

  <hr>

  <!-- THREE -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="itemForSale3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Item for Sale:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="itemForSale3" name="itemForSale3">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="quantity3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Quantity:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="quantity3" name="quantity3">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="price3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Price:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price3" name="price3">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="itemThreeImg1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Image 1:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="file" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png" class="form-control" name="itemThreeImg1">

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="itemThreeImg2" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Image 2:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="file" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png" class="form-control" name="itemThreeImg2">

    </div>
  </div>

  <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">
</form>
```

Would there be anyway for me to only get the parts that say <-- TWO --> and <-- THREE -->, to only appear if someone click a "additional files" button?

I tried looking but I couldn't find a nice and easy way to do it. Thanks guys

Comment: You just want to hide and show and `<hr>` (*or do you mean everything after that but the submit button*)? Anyways just place a wrapper `div` around the item, give in an id. Then `.show()` when you click the  "additional files" button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a class to the divs you want to show—like, `class="show-onclick"`—and then use jQuery to handle the click event:

The HTML would look like this:

```
<div class="show-onclick form-group">
    <label for="itemForSale2" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Item for Sale:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="itemForSale2" name="itemForSale2">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="show-onclick form-group">
    <label for="quantity2" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Quantity:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="quantity2" name="quantity2">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="show-onclick form-group">
    <label for="major2" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Price:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price2" name="price2">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="show-onclick form-group">
    <label for="itemTwoImg1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Image 1:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="file" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png" class="form-control" name="itemTwoImg1">

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="show-onclick form-group">
    <label for="itemTwoImg2" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Image 2:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="file" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png" class="form-control" name="itemTwoImg2">

    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- END TWO -->

  <hr>

  <!-- THREE -->
  <div class="show-onclick form-group">
    <label for="itemForSale3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Item for Sale:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="itemForSale3" name="itemForSale3">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="show-onclick form-group">
    <label for="quantity3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Quantity:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="quantity3" name="quantity3">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="show-onclick form-group">
    <label for="price3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Price:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price3" name="price3">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="show-onclick form-group">
    <label for="itemThreeImg1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Image 1:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="file" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png" class="form-control" name="itemThreeImg1">

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="show-onclick form-group">
    <label for="itemThreeImg2" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Image 2:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="file" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png" class="form-control" name="itemThreeImg2">

    </div>
  </div>

  <button type="button" id="additional-files">Additional files</button>
```

And the JavaScript would look like this:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#additional-files').click(function() {
        $('.show-onclick').show();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: When I push additional files, it redirects to my submit.php which is what my submit button on the bottom should do

Comment: Okay perfect! Forgot to ask, how do I even hide them to begin with?

Comment: In your CSS, do this: `.show-onclick { display: none; }`. That will hide them by default.